# Dependency Injection Patterns stand alone implementaion

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection

In Mark Seemann lists four DI patterns in his book **Dependency Injection in .NET**:

1. Constructor injection
2. Property injection
3. Method injection
4. Ambient context

He also talks about the concept of the composition root.

**My question is**:
Is it possible to have a Composition Root in an application, without it making use of any DI patterns? Or does the Composition Root always inherently require DI?

Comment: What do you mean by "stand alone" though? And what are the 4 patterns? This question is both unclear and too broad.

Comment: The author mentiend in the book 4 DI patterns composition root, constructor injection , method injection and property injection each pattern has a usage and an implementation but I need to understand if it's meant to use each pattern separately specially the composition root or I have to use at least one pattern along with the composition root, this is not mentioned explicitly

Comment: You can use a combination of them if you wish. Most containers will allow that.

Comment: The "Composition root" is wherever you are calling `.Build()`. The default `IServiceCollection` would use "constructor injection". Though MVC controllers would use "property injection" and "method injection", nothing else in dotnet (that I can think of right now) uses anything else. (https://auth0.com/blog/dependency-injection-in-dotnet-core/)

Comment: Yes, you can use each pattern on its own, but you'll get the most benefit out of applying DI holistically. This means you at least use Composition Root (CR) with either Constructor Injection or Property Injection (or a combination). Method Injection is primarily applied outside the CR. Since you're reading the book, I would advise reading the [second edition](https://mng.bz/BYNl). In that edition Mark (and I) make a stronger argument against property injection.

Comment: Thanks @Steven , I am really more than happy to get this answer from you. What makes me confused that I couldn't get how to apply the pure DI with only using CR. So it would be so kind of you to just guide me with an example for such an implementation with only CR.

Comment: For the second edition, the book's code samples are in [this](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples) repository. There are a few examples of Pure DI in there, such as [this](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/RightECommerce/src/Commerce.Web/CommerceControllerActivator.cs) and [this](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/UWPProductManagementClient/src/ProductManagement.UWPClient/App.xaml.cs).

Comment: And [here's](https://github.com/DependencyInjection-2nd-edition/codesamples/blob/master/AopECommerce/src/Commerce.Web.PureDI/CommerceControllerActivator.cs) a third example. Again, note that this is for the second edition, that I coauthored, so the examples are related to that book and sometimes differ quite a lot from the first edition. Since I wasn't involved in writing the first edition, I can't quickly point you to examples, but examples are likely sparse, because the second edition has a greater emphasis on Pure DI than the first edition did.